# How to Upload image on server using webservice in titanium android/iOS?

Tags: android, image, web-services, titanium, base64

I want to convert and image into base64 format and then upload that onto the server but the base64 string is so large that it gives me error on web that parameter not received.Any idea to send the complete string to the server using the below webservice? Here is below service that i tried.

```
var xhrAddclient = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhrAddclient.open('POST', webservice_url);
    xhrAddclient.send({
        method : "addclient",
        image : base64string,
    });

    xhrAddclient.setTimeout(10000);

    xhrAddclient.onerror = function() {
        showAlertBox('Service timed out. Please try again.');

    };

    xhrAddclient.onload = function() {
        showAlertBox("Client added successfully.");


    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Check here: http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/titanium-tutorial-how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-server/

and here: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/File+Uploads+and+Downloads#FileUploadsandDownloads-Fileupload

or just:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.send(file);
```